# Demean and scale an entire sample or groups seperatly?

Tags: logistic, classification, data-preprocessing

If I have some data of 40 samples, 20 belong to a patient group and 20 to a control group. Before running the data through my logistic regression classifier to try and classify who is a patient and who isn't I want to demean and scale the data. My question is do I demean and scale the entire data set together or do I first break the data set up into the two groups(patients and controls) , demean and scale and then combine the data again and feed it into the classifier ?

What are the reasons for picking one over the other ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ordinary logistic regression (as opposed to, say, regularized logistic regression) is effectively invariant to the means and SDs of the features. Changing the means and SDs of the features would only rescale the coefficients; any good method of computing confidence intervals (CIs) for the coefficients should give exactly analogous CIs, and any good significance test should make the same decision.

As for the dependent variable (DV), you shouldn't try to change the mean or SD of a logistic regression model's DV because the DV ought to be dummy-coded (generally just 0 and 1), and you'll break the dummy codes if you transform the variable.

All the above concerns transformations to the entire dataset, without segregating by group. Segregating by group seems counterproductive, assuming you wanted to include group as a feature in the model, because the two transformations will interfere with estimating the effect of group, particularly, any interaction terms involving group.